# How to configure Hibernate in Spring project for Heroku Postgres

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, heroku, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to create a very simple Spring project to work with the Postgres addon in Heroku, but I haven't got any of the methods described in the Heroku docs below to work: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-relational-databases-on-heroku-with-java

The last thing I tried is to create a hibernate.cfg.xml document using the environment variables which Heroku creates for the database. I've spent over 10 hours trying all manners of different configurations, like creating a BasicDataSource bean, configuring the database in application.yml and application.properties, etc. I've also tried using a H2 database in Heroku, which I got working.

My hibernate.cfg.xml looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">${JDBC_DATABASE_URL}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">${JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">${JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here are my dependencies from pom.xml:

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The Java classes are very basic, but here they are;
Application:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller:

```java
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    TestRepository repository;

    @PostMapping(name = "/add")
    public TestObject postObject(@RequestBody TestObject object) {
        return repository.save(object);
    }

    @GetMapping(name = "/get")
    public Iterable<TestObject> getFirst() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

The persistable object:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "testobjects")
public class TestObject {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String data;

    public TestObject(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public TestObject() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Lastly, my repository:

```java
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<TestObject, Long> {
}
```

Accessing any page in the application shows the error/exception:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

I expect mapping from /get to display an initially empty list, and /post to add a TestObject to said list. If you want tot see the heroku logs from when I last ran a new version of the application, they're on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/0TQys5Me

EDIT1:
Heroku logs with Hibernate command output and stack trace: https://pastebin.com/s86UdHTx

Comment: can you update error message with stack trace

Comment: @Deadpool post edited

Comment: It clearly says table does not exist @AntonH

Comment: Have you created your tables in the Heroku database? You can do it manually with `heroku pg:psql` or follow this guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/running-database-migrations-for-java-apps

Comment: Shouldn't hibernate take care of creating the tables if they do not exist? At least this was the case without any further configuration when I've used MySQL and H2